# Properties appearing as nil when used but print to debug console prior to use?

Tags: ios, json, swift, google-maps, google-places-api

If there is anything else that could be linking to the issue please let me know so I can try and provide more details. I am bout a week in and I can't seem to find the issue. It will probably be something that will cause me to want to chuck the computer at the wall but I can't seem to figure it out :(

- The issue seems to have isolated down to the coordinate variables, however the issue could still be associated with how the classes are constructed but I am not able to identify how they would be.
- I am able to print Current Location Coordinates to the screen prior to the request should be made but I get the following error within the JSON  when calling the method that will be sending the api request

> "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST",

Google documentation claims that:

> "INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing."

What I am experiencing is:

- With hard coded coordinates I am able to conduct a search and return JSON successfully.
- I am able to successfully acquire Current Location Coordinates.
- However; I am not able to interpolate Current Location Coordinates into the Search Query.

This is a good chunk of code that I believe is all that will be needed to grasp the issue. I appreciate any suggestions that could lead to solving the issue:

```
// all classes have their own swift file

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{

let currentLocation = CurrentLocation()
let downloadData    = DownLoadData()

override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>)
{
    if !didFindMyLocation
    {
        let myLocation: CLLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
        currentLocation.coordinate = myLocation.coordinate
        currentLocation.latitude   = myLocation.coordinate.latitude
        currentLocation.longitude  = myLocation.coordinate.longitude

        didFindMyLocation = true

        print(currentLocation.coordinates) // prints coordinates correctly

        downLoadData.downloadAllLocations({ () -> () in  //request I am attempting to make that outputs,
        //"status" : "INVALID_REQUEST",
        })
    }
}

class CurrentLocation: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
override init()
{
    super.init()
}

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

//THE CULPRITS!
var latitude   : CLLocationDegrees!
var longitude  : CLLocationDegrees!

}

// typealias in a swift file of its own.

import foundation

typealias DownLoadComplete = () -> ()


class DownloadData: NSObject
{
let currentLocation = CurrentLocation()

override init()
{
    super.init()
}

func downloadAllLocations(completed: DownloadComplete)
{
    //hardcoded coordinates output correct JSON Response. So Why Cant I Interpolate the coordinates from my current location???
    let URL_Search = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
    let urlString  = "\(URL_Search)location=\(currentLocation.latitude),\(currentLocation.longitude)&radius=\(searchRadius)&types=\(searchType)&key=\(API_ServerKey)"

    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!
    print(url) // outputs nil,nil in the currentLocation.latitude and currentLocation.longitude spots
    Alamofire.request(.GET,url).responseJSON { (response) -> Void in

        switch response.result
        {
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value
            {
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(json) // If hardcoded coordinates are inserted then I the json is outputted. If current location is attempted then I receive an INVALID_REQUEST error.

                if let results = json["results"].array
                {
                    for result in results {
                        if let places = result["place"].string
                        {
                            self.places = place
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }

        completed()
     }
  }

}
```

Testing the output by a print(currentLocation.coordinates) before i send the request (downLoadData.downLoadAllLocation[which has a print(url) being called]) the output to the debug console is:

> CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33233141, longitude: -122.0312186)
>   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=nil,nil
>   ...etc

The issue here is that the coordinates interpolated into the search query are appearing as nil, nil? Ive tried manipulating code around. But no luck... It seems so odd that they get printed but then in the search they appear as nil. How can that be??

Comment: What're you trying to build

Comment: What are the hardcoded coordinates and other values that are passed to the url? Is any of the variables used in the query str construction an optional? If so then perhaps its going into the query url as Optional("...") and so you might be getting invalid request.

Comment: Try printing the search query url and see what's the actual url that's passed to the GET call?

Comment: so i guess this holds to the original question. Why are they nil IF I am able to actually print(currentLocation.latitude) and print(currentLocation.longitude) right before I send the request and get the correct coordinates outputted to the debug console.

Comment: Its interesting because I'm converting all my code from one Massive View Controller into classes. When it was one MVC it ran fine. Now it doesn't........... So Im thinking it has to do something with the classes but I haven't been able to find any information on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DownloadData` class refers to a `currentLocation` variable (presumably an instance of `CurrentLocation`, but this variable isn't defined anywhere in your code sample. I assume it's a member variable of `ViewController`, in which case the question is: How does `DownloadData` know about it?

You may need to pass `currentLocation` to `downloadData.downloadAllLocations()` as a parameter.

Comment: The appreciation I have for you help is unbelievable! Thank you. Ended up simply having to insert currentLocation as the parameter.